Script that puts google sheet to calendar duplicates events every time it is run
I created a script that copies events from a google sheet and ads it to the calendar. Every time the sheet is updated the calendar needs to be updated. The problem is that the events are duplicated every time the script runs, i don't want duplicates. Below the code:
function copyCalender() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("xxxx@group.calendar.google.com");
  var signups = spreadsheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  for(x=0;x<signups.length;x++) {
    var notAvailable=signups[x]

    var busy = notAvailable[0]
    var startTime = notAvailable[1]
    var endTime = notAvailable [2]

    eventCal.createEvent(busy, startTime, endTime);
  }
}

i expect the code to not dublicate events and only copy new events.

Your events are being duplicated because you don't have any option in place to contrast whether the event has been created for the provided data or not. What I've done is use "helper columns" to store the EventID and use it as an identifier. This might not be the most elegant solution, but it's what I've done. Don't forget that you can hide the "Helper column". 
function createEvents() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('SheetX');
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("xxxx@group.calendar.google.com");
  var signups = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  console.log(signups)

  for (x = 1; x < signups.length; x++) {
    var notAvailable = signups[x];
// Please make sure the column references matches your data
    var busy = notAvailable[1];
    var startTime = new Date(notAvailable[2]);
    var endTime = new Date(notAvailable[3]);
    var eventId = notAvailable[4];
    var helperColumn = notAvailable[5];
    if (!helperColumn) {
      if (eventId) {
        // Try to get the event by ID
        try {
          var event = eventCal.getEventById(eventId);
          if (event) {
            // Event already exists
            event.setTitle(busy);
            event.setTime(startTime, endTime);
          } else {
            // Create a new event if not found
            event = eventCal.createEvent(busy, startTime, endTime);
            ss.getRange(x + 1, 5).setValue(event.getId()); //Stores EventID 
          }
        } catch (e) {
          // Event not found, we need to create it
          event = eventCal.createEvent(busy, startTime, endTime);
          ss.getRange(x + 1, 4).setValue(event.getId()); 
        }
      } else {
        // Create a new event if no event ID
        var event = eventCal.createEvent(busy, startTime, endTime);
        ss.getRange(x + 1, 5).setValue(event.getId()); 
      }
      // Mark the row as processed in the helper column
      ss.getRange(x + 1, 6).setValue("Event Created");
    }
  }
}


This is how I had my data in the spreadsheet:


My spreadsheet has no data in Event ID and Processed. Those are the events that are not created. When both columns are empty, the code gives error: Exception: The parameters (String,number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getRange. When I put random strings in both columns the code runs and the event is not created as expected. So the problem is the event does not get created and ID is not generated, nor processed.

Mine were not there either, the code is expected to print it there after the event ID is created. Actually to work, the EventID and Processed column must be empty.

Can you share a test spreadsheet? I just wanna see how is your data, maybe it is a reference issue and I can adjust it to your needs :D
Edit: Just make sure the spreadsheet doesn't contain any personal info and it is set as "anyone with the link"

Issue resolved. I changed out getSheetByName and replaced with getActiveSheet. Thank you for the help
